How do I move the origin of a logarithmic spiral?
Context: I'm a high school junior (in pre-calculus) and I'm trying to teach myself how to graph a logarithmic spiral for a math/art project.
Basically, I need to move the center of a spiral from the origin at $(0,0)$ to $(-13,11)$. Is this even possible? I figured out how to move the $x$-coordinate, but I'm stuck on the $y$-axis. Would it be easier to realign my entire project? I'm hoping it won't come to that, seeing as I've spent $2$ weeks on this already, but it's not impossible, if that turns out to be my only option. Thanks in advance :)
tl;dr: How do you change the $y$-coordinate of a spiral's center?

Welcome to MSE! <> If the existing answers don't help, it would be good to edit the question (i.e., please don't respond in the comments :) to explain (i) How you are describing a logarithmic spiral (parametrically, as a polar graph, ...) and (ii) How you moved the $x$-coordinate, and if appropriate, (iii) Why the same technique does not allow you to move the $y$-coordinate.

If you have the spiral equation in parametric form $(x=ae^{b\theta} \cos \theta, y=ae^{b\theta} \sin \theta)$, you simply use $(x=13+ae^{b\theta} \cos \theta, y=-11+ae^{b\theta} \sin \theta)$ to shift your spiral.

If you have an equation of the form $f(x,y) = g(x,y),$
then you can accomplish a translation by change of variables $x'=x-x_0$ and $y'=y-y_0.$
That is, $f(x-x_0, y-y_0) = g(x-x_0, y-y_0)$ should do the trick.
For example, say your equation is $y^2 = x^3 - x$, and we want to shift the graph $10$ ticks up and $8$ ticks to the right. Then $(x_0, y_0) = (8,10),$ and after substituting, $(y-8)^2 =  (x-10)^3 - (x-10)$ will be a translated graph.
In fact, we can do even more general transformations in this way.
Vertical stretching by a factor of $a$ can be achieved by $y'=ay,$ or horizontal stretching with $x'=ax,$ or even a rotation by $\theta$ can be achieved with $x'=x\cos(\theta) - y\sin(\theta)$ and $y'=y\cos(\theta)+x\sin(\theta).$
A lot more can be achieved with substitutions like these, and everything I've mentioned here is actually a linear transformation in general: if you want to learn more about them, you might be interested in https://www.3blue1brown.com/lessons/linear-transformations
